# Sending data from dropdownlist to database

Tags: php, html-select

We are having troubles with our php session.
Trying to add a patient to a database, linked to the doctor that is curing the patient.

We have a select from the existing doctors in the database. They show up in the dropdown list.
But when we are trying to send the selected doctor to the database (the php session), there is no addition to the database. All the other inputs (patient name, patient birth date, etc) are put in the database, except the data from the dropdown list.

**Add_patient.php**

```
Doctor:<br>
<select name="doctor">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <?php
    $config = parse_ini_file("divkey.ini.php", true);
    include("connect/connect_mysql.php");
    $opdracht = "SELECT * FROM gebruiker ORDER BY id";
    $resultaat = mysql_query($opdracht);

    while ($rij = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat)) {
        $id = $rij['id'];
        $name = $rij['name'];
        $fname = $rij['fname'];
        ?> 
        <option value ="<?php $id;?>"><?php echo"$name $fname" ?></option>
        <?php 
    } ?>
</select>
```

**Session_add.php**

```
$doctor = $_POST['doctor'];

# query
```

Our query from session_add.php works. Just the not for the `$_POST['doctor']`.

```
# query                
$opdracht = "INSERT INTO patient ( `name`, `fname`, `geslacht`, `doctor`, `straatnaam`, `huisnummer`, `postcode`, `gemeente`, `telefoonnummer`, `patientnummer`, `land`, `bloedgroep`, `gsmnummer`, `geboortedatum`, `geboorteplaats`, `taal`, `nationaliteit`, `rijksregisternummer`, `huisarts` )
VALUES ('".$name."', '".$fname."', '".$geslacht."', '".$doctor."','".$straatnaam."' ,'".$huisnummer."' , '".$postcode."' , '".$gemeente."', '".$telefoonnummer."',
   '".$patientnummer."','".$land."', '".$bloedgroep."', '".$gsmnummer."', '".$geboortedatum."', '".$geboorteplaats."', '".$taal."', '".$nationaliteit."','".$rijksregisternummer."', '".$huisarts."')";
# other values are not important, it's in Dutch and these values are sent to the database

# doing query
$result = mysql_query($opdracht) or die(mysql_error()); 
# we use or die(mysql_error())
```

The query is executed, a 0 (zero) is added to the database instead of the selected doctor.

Comment: You could try removing the whitespace in `value =`. Not sure it's the issue, but some browsers are fussy about that sort of thing.

Comment: try <?php echo $id;?> and also select list name =doctor[]

Comment: Did you forget the closing bracket in your while loop?

Comment: @errieman: No, it's just indented a lot.

Comment: is the form actually sent with post?

Comment: This is why you should never use inline PHP

Comment: @nvanesch: yes, it is send, we checked it

Comment: @RakeshSharma: didn't solve the problem, thanks anyway!

Comment: Please show your query, it's hard to answer your question otherwise. And did you look in your network panel to see what's actually sent to the server?

Comment: did you try var_dump-ing $_POST and see if it is in there? if it is actually in $_POST['doctor'] then something might simply be wring in the query, so add the query

Comment: use `mysql_query($opdracht); or die(mysql_error();` to find if your query gets a problem

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Amir nvanesch: post updated with the query.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead (using MySQLi or PDO). Moreover, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). And again, look at your network panel to see if the correct value is actually sent to the server.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: how do you check that? the database was made in phpmyadmin and is on our school server (personal space available for all students)

Comment: Use Chrome or Firebug → open network panel → send request → look at network panel to see if the value is sent correctly.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: Thanks, I checked, no value is send to the server

Comment: Or did you mean the SQL injection? It's just that you use user contents (in this case the `$_POST` variable) in a database query without escaping it first. 2. Ok, now you need to know *why* no value is sent. Can you show the HTML that is output to the browser?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: you mean the session or the add_patient?

Comment: The one that contains the form, so add_patient.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem, it was in the sql query. With var_dump($_POST)
I checked the values that were sent to the session, these were the right ones. 
In the SQL query, there was '".$doctor."' 
This was wrong, it should be '.$doctor.' (recognised as id) 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value ="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $name.$fname; ?></option>
```

Try this.